# Angular Route with .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an .NET MVC using AngularJS for the front end on Mono.

I have a simple `HomeController` with a simple `return View()` that loads the main page of my project.

My main `Index.cshtml` looks like:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/#/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>            
    <li><a href="/#/routeThree">Route Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I have my javascript setup as such:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/routeOne', {
            templateUrl: 'RoutesDemo/One'
        })
        .when('/routeTwo', {
            template: 'RoutesDemo/two'
        })
        .when('/routeThree', {
            template: 'RoutesDemo/three'
        });
    });

        //var app = angular.module('app');
    app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Hello World';
    });
})();
```

So at this point my expected behavior is that if I click on the `Route One` link, the app should invoke the `RoutesDemoController's One` method, which renders some partial view :`One. It Worked!

but this doesn't happen.

Instead only the link changes but I don't see any activity in the browser or in the network tab.

Did I miss a step?

EDIT:

The main page I am viewing to hit `Index.cshtml` is `localhost:8080`

I am able to hit `localhost:8080/RoutesDemo/One` which does return my partial view.

When I click on my anchor link for Route One, my url is `http://localhost:8080/#/routeOne`

Comment: Try giving the html templates like   templateUrl: 'RoutesDemo/One.html'. Are you expecting the Angular to call MVC routing ?

Comment: @SanishJoseph I tried renaming that template to `.html`. It still did not route me

Comment: Do you have an actual HTML like One.html in that path?

Comment: Here is an Angular example, 

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: Are you able to see any error in the browser console?

Comment: hm. I guess I am expecting it to hit my MVC controller instead of serving up that template. I was following this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Comment: @SanishJoseph no browser errors

Comment: I hope, you haven't missed to include Angular's ngRoute.
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: That is included.

Comment: Are you trying this in chrome or IE?

Comment: Try adding this like just below the routes in Angular,

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); ...... Something like 

.when('/routeThree', {
            template: 'RoutesDemo/three'
        });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: @Rhs could you please check my answer, and check what I suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an **outlet** for your route templates to be written to.  Angular provides a special directive, `ng-view`, for this purpose.  When a particular route is processed by the route provider, the `.innerHtml` of the `ng-view` element is dynamically replaced with the contents from the `template` or `templateUrl` property.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Change your index to look like this:

```html
<body ng-controller="AppController"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/#/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>            
    <li><a href="/#/routeThree">Route Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view />
</body>
```

Comment: I think that's already present in the link he is following, 

<div ng-view></div>

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Comment: The question didn't suggest the OP was following a tutorial, they may have said that in the comments though;  I am simply going by the code posted in the question body, which *clearly* does not show this component.

Comment: Yes. That's true.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!